GPT-2 model from hugging face always generate same result
Why were all the results I got from the GPT-2 model the same no matter what I fed into it?
The following are my operating details.
First I download the needed files from the official website. These files included config.json, merges.txt, pytorch_model.bin, tokenizer.json, tokenizer_config.json and vocab.json. Then I stored them in the root path of the project ./gpt2.
Second, I loaded the model and predicted the next word based on the input context. The code is displayed as follows.

model = GPT2Model.from_pretained('./gpt2') 
gpt_tokenizer=GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('./gpt2')
start_context="The white man worked as a " 
ids_text=gpt_tokenizer(start_ontext,return_tensor='pt') 
output=model(**ids_text) 
output=output.last_hidden_state[:,-1,:] 
idx_next=torch.argmax(output,dim=-1,keepdim=True) 
ids=idx_next.squeeze(0) 
text=gpt_tokenizer.decode(ids.tolist()) 
print(text) 

Here, the text always indicates age, even though I changed the start_context to other, like "I see a cat under".
I hope someone can tell me the reason and help me work it out, thanks.

The reason is that you got the ouput of shape [batch, hidden_size], which is 1,768 I guess. You cannot fit it into a argmax and do tokenization as 768 is the dimension of vector space instead of vocab.
Try using GPT2LMHeadModel:
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "2"
import torch

# Model and tokenizer paths
model_path = "/mnt/sda/agent_mxz/models/gpt2"
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_path)

# Input texts
texts = ["Replace me by any text you'd like.", "Hello, this is", "Write a story for me."]

# Ensure padding is done on the left
tokenizer.padding_side = "left"

# Define PAD Token = EOS Token
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
model.config.pad_token_id = model.config.eos_token_id
model.config.do_sample = False

# Tokenize the inputs with padding
encoded_inputs = tokenizer(texts, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True)
print(encoded_inputs)
# Get model output
outputs = model(**encoded_inputs)
# outputs1 = model.generate()
# Print the outputs
# print(outputs[0][1])
print(tokenizer.batch_decode(torch.argmax(outputs[0], dim=-1)))

It will give you ['. the with a means, want like.\n', ',HelloHelloHelloHelloHello Hello Hello hello hello', ',Write""Write write write the I.']

Yes, according to your code, my model can change results based on different input strings. However, in my point, I think the model will output the next word based on the context, but the result does not seem to be. As well, the results don't make sense.

大模型最后是一个词分类来产生输出，大概是个3w分类，所以你用768的768分类当然不会有输出。用768后面出的线性层才有输出。
